# Set a cookie in Laravel 5+ without response

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to set a cookie in a function that's not going to return a response. The function is called from a middleware.

Middleware:

```
// Verify user
        $userId = $userService->verify($email, $key);
        if ($userId) {
            $userService->authenticate($userId, $key);

            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return response('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
```

is calling $userService->authenticate:

```
// Get user
    $user = $this->getById($id);
    // Get user zipcode
    $user->zipcode = $this->getZipcodeById($id);
    // Set session
    Session::set('user', $user);

    if (!Cookie::has('user_forever')) {
      // SET COOKIE   
    }
```

I have tried to return a response in authenticate but it doen't work. I can't get it to work.. So I appreciates all help!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `queue()` as:

```
Cookie::queue('key', 'value', 10);
```

Comment: Damn it, i read that Cookie::queue was removed in Laravel 5, but it sure works! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[according to docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#cookies) you can generate a cookie instance using the cookie helper,

```
$cookie = cookie('name', 'value', $minutes);
```

But it won't be sent back to client unless it is attached to a response instance. Try sending from middleware like below

```
$response = $next($request);

return $response->cookie($cookie);
```

**Untested Code**